# Moving points within ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I am attempting to create a tool through ModelBuilder that creates address points from parcel polygons. I have added the following tools to the Model. Feature to Point -> Append the point data to our address point feature class. I have been successful with the tool.

I wanted to know if there is a way to move the points after they are appended by let's say 000000.1 of an inch within the tool. I need the points to be displaced by a small amount so that the remaining attribute fields are picked up by ArcObjects (Zip Code & City Boundary). I know the other option is to use the "move command" within the editor toolbar. To have this run in one Python tool would be the ideal result. I have attached the exported Python Code from ModelBuilder, as well as the screenshot of the current model.

[image]

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy


# Local variables:
FIREADM_Parcels_MCT = "PARCELS MCT UPLOAD"
Points = "%scratchGDB%\\Points"
FIREADM_AddrPoints = Points
FIREADM_AddrPoints__3_ = "FIREADM.AddrPoints"

# Process: Feature To Point
arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(FIREADM_Parcels_MCT, Points, "CENTROID")

# Process: Append
arcpy.Append_management("%scratchGDB%\\Points", FIREADM_AddrPoints__3_, 
"NO_TEST", "STREET_NUMBER \"STREET_NUMBER\")

 def XYsetVALUE( shape, X_value, Y_value):
   myMoveX = 0.001
   myMoveY = 0.001
   point = shape.getPart(0)
   point.X = X_value + myMoveX
   point.Y = Y_value + myMoveY
   return point
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the location of a point's geometry using the field calculator.  Just add a field calculator to the model and update the `Shape` field using your function.

**[This blog post](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2011/12/06/how-to-update-the-location-of-a-point-feature-and-its-xy-fields/)** explains how to do it pretty clearly.  The code is essentially the same as what you've written.